# Converting HTML design to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started a website and I need to create a wordpress theme exactly identical to it. I followed a tutorial that showed how to cut down the website in pieces and call them via php like wordpress does. It looked quite simple but I didn't manage to get it to work.

Here are my pieces :
HEADER.PHP:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Mairie de </title>

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="assets/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<!--HEADER PART-->


 <div class="headcontainer">
 
  <div class="menuheader">
  
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
         </button>
                </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Actualités</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Plus d'infos</a></li> 
           <li><a href="#">Activités du mois</a></li> 
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
         </ul>
         <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>       </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
  
  </div>
 
  <div class="container-full" id="logorow">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
       <div class="col-sm-4"> <center><img src="/img/mafate.svg" style="width:30%"></center> </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      </div>
       </div>
       <div class="imgheader">
  </div>
   
 </div>
```

INDEX.PHP :

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="container" id="pagecontent">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post-header">
       <div class="date"><?php the_time( 'M j y' ); ?></div>
       <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
       <div class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></div>
    </div><!--end post header-->
    <div class="entry clear">
       <?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
       <?php the_content(); ?>
       <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
       <?php wp_link_pages(); ?> </div>
    <!--end entry-->
    <div class="post-footer">
       <div class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link( 'Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?></div>
    </div><!--end post footer-->
    </div><!--end post-->
<?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
    <div class="navigation index">
       <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries' ); ?></div>
       <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?></div>
    </div><!--end navigation-->
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

FOOTER.PHP

```html
<div class="footer">TEST</div>
</body>

</html>
```

FUNCTIONS.PHP :

```html
<?php
function theme_add_bootstrap() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . 'style.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
function bootstrapstarter_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    $dependencies = array('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstarter-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), $dependencies ); 
}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrapstarter_enqueue_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrapstarter_enqueue_scripts' );

function bootstrapstarter_wp_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bootstrapstarter_wp_setup' );

if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
function bootstrapstarter_register_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('header-menu', __( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'bootstrapstarter_register_menu' );

?>
```

STYLE.CSS

```html
/*
Theme Name: themeprojetocr
Theme URI: blank
Author: M.François
Author URI: blank
Description: blank
Version: 1.0
Text Domain: bootstrapstarter
*/

 body {
      position: relative; 
      padding:0%;
      
  }
  
/*HEADER*/
  .headcontainer {
 width:100%;
 min-height:500px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 
 
}
  .imgheader {
  width:100%;
min-height:400px;
 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    background-image:url('img/mountainheader.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
  .logoheader {
  position:relative;
  min-height:50px;    
 
}
#logorow {
margin-top:50px;

}
  .menuheader {
 
}
.spacer {
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
}
/*HEADER*/

/*CONTENT*/
#pagecontent {
 background-color:#E4E8ED;
 width:90%;
 padding:2%;
}
/*CONTENT*/
```

Needless to say that I didn't figure out wordpress functions yet and this is poorly written with probable errors.
The result is a blank page with the text as if the style.css didn't load. Also the pictures don't load even though in Visual Studio they show up fine so no path error.
I'm on a localhost with XAMPP so no links available.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The assets including stylesheets, js and images won't load directly.

```
<link href="assets/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The above code is not pointing to your css file. So you have to give it full path and you can use wordpress `get_template_directory_uri()` predefined function

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is the **better and recommended** way for including css and js in Wordpress:

```
//embed this code in functions.php file
function add_theme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/base.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');

  wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

For more detail, check WordPress Docs for adding [CSS and JS](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edted the header.php and cut all <link> and <script> and I added your piece of code to the function.php but the result is still the same. No css and no pictures.

Comment: And btw I don't need base.css I just need style.css but it's not loading either

Comment: 1. Make sure `style.css` is available in main theme folder. `Style.css` must should be under this path: `wp-content/themes/YourThemeName/style.css` 2. Try this code for including `style.css` file in header. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>">`

Comment: This worked fine. Pictures are now loading and divs have their style. Only issue left is it's still not loading bootstrap I'll try to see what I can do. Thank your very much

Comment: Also the svg is not loading. Can wordpress show .svg files ?EDIT: the problem is the way php gets directory paths right ? what is get_template_directory equivalent for pictures ?

Comment: I think the issue here is that I have to call these functions (the ones that add bootstrap and jquery) at one point in my header isn't it ? How can I do that ?

Comment: Use this code for including bootstrap `<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` WordPress doesn't allow SVG but you can [try this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/scalable-vector-graphics-svg/) to work with SVGs. `get_template_directory()` returns theme path so you have to specify subfolder like `assets/images/abc.jpg` etc. Check [wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) for more detail. And don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: One last thing please what about jquery and bootstrap.js do I add anything after their path like the rel=stylesheet here ?

Comment: just add this piece of  code `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` for all of your CSS and JS files.

Comment: I highly recommend taking an online course, or at least watching several video tutorials on a current version of Wordpress.  If your issues include the fundamentals of any CMS framework that you're currently working within, the questions will be endless - because it doesn't just stop here.  The last thing you want to do is take a task that may last five minutes, and turn it into four hours of "what is this and how do I do it?"